# S3 Delete files inside a folder using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How can we delete files inside an S3 Folder using boto3?

P.S - Only files should be deleted, folder should remain.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You would have to use [`delete_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_object):

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.delete_object(
    Bucket='my-bucket',
    Key='invoices/January.pdf'
)
```

If you are asking how to delete *ALL* files within a folder, then you would need to loop through all objects with a given Prefix:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
PREFIX = 'folder1/'

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=BUCKET, Prefix=PREFIX)

for object in response['Contents']:
    print('Deleting', object['Key'])
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=object['Key'])
```

Also, please note that **folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3**. The Key (filename) of an object contains the **full path** of the object. If necessary, you can create a zero-length file with the name of a folder to make the folder 'appear', but this is not necessary. Merely creating a folder in a given path will make any subfolders sort of 'appear', but they will 'disappear' when the object is deleted (since folders don't actually exist).

Comment: Thanks, I had taken a similar approach

Comment: is it possible to use delete_objects https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.delete_objects to delete multiple objects at once using prefix of objects. e.g abc_320.jpg, abc_320.webp, bcd_640.jpg, abc_640.web, so I want to delete all 3 that starts with `abc_`  prefix

Comment: @AlwaysSunny You can pass a list, but the list should contain the **full path** of each object to be deleted. It cannot contain wildcards or partial prefixes. However, you could use a bit of Python to reduce the list down to a certain prefix, eg `[key for key in list if key.startswith('abc_')]`

Comment: With this I get AccessDenine error: `exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied`  I need to add ExpectedBucketOwner but I don't know my Account ID, I have Access key and Secrect Key. Can anybody help on this please?

Comment: @KishanMehta An `Access Denied` error suggests that you do not have the `s3:DeleteObject` permission assigned to the credentials being used.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I updated my comment. Do you think so?

Comment: @KishanMehta Please create a new Question rather than asking in a comment in an old question. Make sure you add all the details related to your question.

Comment: This solution worked very well! Thanks